# Incomplete type in C on variable size structure

Tags: c, typedef, incomplete-type

Up to now, I've been using `void *` as a way to encapsulate private data in C. The idea is : the user should not bother with the internal, and just request exposed functions.

Hence for example :

```
typedef void* myPrivateType;

myPrivateType createMPt(int someArg);
int doSomething(myPrivateType mpt, int someOtherArg);
void freeMpt(myPrivateType mpt);
```

This works well at hiding the internal of `myPrivateType`. However, there is one last minor catch : `void*` is so permissive, that the compiler will silently accept any kind of pointer, and not trigger any warning in case of incorrect type.
This looks like a small issue, but it just increases the likelyhood that a user improperly uses the interface and lose a lot of time trying to debug what's wrong.

As a consequence, I'm now leaning on using [incomplete types](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/819-5265/bjals/index.html) instead of `void*`, as a stricter way to control type during compilation.

Hence the previous example becomes as follows :

```
typedef struct foo* myPrivateType;

myPrivateType createMPt(int someArg);
int doSomething(myPrivateType mpt, int someOtherArg);
void freeMpt(myPrivateType mpt);
```

As you can see, almost nothing has changed, only the typedef. It works better than previous example as now, if the user provides another pointer than `myPrivateType', the compiler will complain, and the error will be immediately caught.

This is a fairly good alternative. Except that, in the "private section" of the code (the `.c` file), I will have to define what `struct foo` is. In some cases, it's quite straightforward, when such content is clearly and statically defined.

But sometimes, the content of `myPrivateType` depends on some variable provided at runtime, and therefore its size may vary. This is no good for a C `struct`, which is supposed to have a defined size at compilation time.

As a workaround, I could for example typedef myPrivateType this way :

```
typedef size_t* myPrivateType;
```

or

```
typedef size_t myPrivateType[];   // equivalent
```

This let the possibility to decide the size later on, as a multiple of `size_t`. But now, `myPrivateType` is more permissive, as any `size_t*` pointer will also fit the bill.

I'm wondering if there is a way to combine both properties, with `myPrivateType` being very strict, hence impossible to confuse with any other type of pointer, but the underlying private data keeping the ability to select its size at runtime.

Comment: "But sometimes, the content of struct foo depends on some variable provided at runtime, and therefore its size may vary" - never at runtime. a struct always has a fixed size. whenever you have something dynamic-sized, it's on the heap, and then you store a pointer, with.. a fixed size;)

Comment: You do know that code needs to be maintained, some times years later, by those that have never seen the code before?   This means all code should be written in, straight forward/simple a manner as still gets the job done.   Trying to 'hide' definitions!  Do you expect the user to be playing with the source code?    Are you trying to develop some job security?   I can assure you that 'hiding' anything within the code will quickly get you pointed toward the door.   what happens when code maintenance is performed?  As soon as they recognize what you have done, they will modify it for visibility.

Comment: the interface needs to be totally visible.  The implementation of the algorithm can be tucked in' behind the interface.  Then, the implementation can be modified without changing the interface.  therefore, the interface (as seen in the associated header file) needs to be completely visible  The implementation could easily be tucked away by configuration control.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
struct myPrivateType { void * private; };
```

Use in essentially exactly the same way that you used to use the raw void pointer. You can expose the whole struct in the header, since there's nothing much the application can do with the void pointer it contains anyway.

This solves the problem of implicit conversions with void * without introducing any irritations beyond the mpt->private dereference within your library functions.

edit: with the `typedef struct myPrivateType myPrivateType;` construct if you prefer.

Comment: That sounds a pretty good idea.
The only major issue I can see is that it is not transparent for the code into `.c` : it's no longer possible to typecast directly `myPrivateType`, since it's a struct, and not a pointer. It's instead necessary to typecast `myPrivateType.private`. It doesn't look unmanageable, but if the original `.c` code expects `myPrivateType` to be a pointer from multiple positions, it can require quite some refactoring effort.

Comment: Probably can't have implicit casts for your library but not the application code though. I'd suggest writing the externally visible create/destroy functions to take the struct, then extract the pointer and call the internal functions with it. But that's because I like having a very thin wrapper providing the api in general. Minimal refactor :)

Comment: Unfortunately, after tests, it's not that good. Being a pointer or not is not a small difference, it totally affects API behavior. It also becomes impossible to tell if the content of the pointer is going to be `const` or not.

Comment: @Cyan Whats the API change involved? The opaque type you once had is now a different opaque type, it's hard to see how that changes anything. Const is not transitive so it's never possible to tell if anything beyond the top level is const. Could we see a longer example of your current code?

Comment: A pointer to an opaque type can be made const or non const, irrespective of the fact that it is complete or incomplete. `void*` and `const void*` for example (which is the way my API used to work previously).

Answer (score 1):

> I'm wondering if there is a way to combine both properties, with myPrivateType being very strict, hence impossible to confuse with any other type of pointer, but the underlying private data keeping the ability to select its size at runtime.

Yes, you can do that quite easily by using:

```
struct foo
{
   int dataType;
   void* fooData;
};

struct FooData1
{
   // ... 
};

struct FooData2
{
   // ... 
};

myPrivateType createMPt(int someArg)
{
   myPrivateType ret = malloc(sizeof(*ret));

   if ( someArg == 10 )
   {
      ret->dataType = 1;
      ret->fooData = malloc(sizeof(FooData1));
   }
   else if ( someArg == 20 )
   {
      ret->dataType = 2;
      ret->fooData = malloc(sizeof(FooData2));
   }
   else
   {
      // ...
   }
}
```

**Update**

If a public function, one that is declared in a .h file, is called many times in a tight loop, and the implementation of that function has to call different functions based of the `dataType` of `struct foo`, you can store a function pointer in `struct foo` instead. This is analogous to the use of virtual tables in C++ classes.

```
struct foo
{
   int dataType;
   void* fooData;
   void (*functionInTightLoop)(void);
};

struct FooData1
{
   // ... 
};

void FooData1Function()
{
}

struct FooData2
{
   // ... 
};

void FooData2Function()
{
}


myPrivateType createMPt(int someArg)
{
   myPrivateType ret = malloc(sizeof(*ret));

   if ( someArg == 10 )
   {
      ret->dataType = 1;
      ret->fooData = malloc(sizeof(FooData1));
      ret->functionInTightLoop = FooData1Function;
   }
   else if ( someArg == 20 )
   {
      ret->dataType = 2;
      ret->fooData = malloc(sizeof(FooData2));
      ret->functionInTightLoop = FooData2Function;
   }
   else
   {
      // ...
   }
}

void tightFunction(myPrivateType foo)
{
   foo->functionInTightLoop();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, you are right it works. 
But it adds one indirection level.
It's sligthly more complex for malloc/free management,
but more importantly, if the `myPrivateType` is going to be used into some hot performance loops, the additional indirection will leave some performance on the table.

Comment: @Cyan, the .c file has to deal with difference in types one way or the other. I showed you one way. I suspect there are other ways to deal with it.

Comment: Are you sure about the performance change? You used to pass a pointer by value, now it's a struct containing a pointer by value. There's a fair chance that'll be exactly the same asm

Comment: @Jon, it depends on how `myPrivateType` is specified. Since it's not shown into @Sahu examples, I've assumed that it re-used the one in my example, which is : `typedef struct foo* myPrivateType;`. In which case, there is indeed an additional reference. But if it uses your convention `typedef struct foo myPrivateType`, then it's no longer an incomplete type, and indeed, the performance difference is going to be minimal, if not null, especially if `void* fooData;` is the first member of the `struct`.

Comment: @Sahu : thanks for the advanced example. I believe it goes a bit beyond what I had in mind (I don't need multiple different functions yet, it's just the size of the content which changes). But that's nonetheless a very interesting read.